# Problems installing Ruby and MSYS2 on Windows 8

Tags: ruby, jekyll, windows-8.1, msys2

I'm trying to run my Jekyll blog (previously created on a Linux machine) on a pc running Windows 8.

I just installed Ruby + MSYS via [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/)

**NOTE** For MSYS I executed:

```
ridk install 1 2 3
```

Now I'm trying to run (in MSYS):

```
gem install jekyll bundler
```

but I'm getting `gem` command is not recognized, same for `ruby`.

Is there something wrong with my installation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved simply adding Ruby `bin` folder to my `PATH` variable.

In my case:

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Ruby/bin
```